# Crash report from JVM

Tags: java, crash, jvm

everybody!
I have some crach reports from JVM - hs_err_pid .logs.
So are they caused by mistakes (exceptions) in my java code? This errors arised from AWT-EventQueue-0:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x4f61b800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=9072, stack(0x4f570000,0x4f5c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000060

The header: 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x761e76d0, pid=8756, tid=9072
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ole32.dll+0x376d0]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#strong text
```

Comment: I would make sure you have the latest OS patches (as it crashed in the OS)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not the result of an error in Java code. It can be the result of:

- Faulty hardware
- A bug in native code called via JNI
- A bug in the JVM
- A bug in the OS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a reinstall of your JVM could help:

http://www.java-forums.org/eclipse/312-exception_access_violation-0xc0000005.html

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the "Problematic frame:ole32.dll" crash is happening from ole32.dll.

Please see similar crash reported
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=e5f1f1011daf96ffffffffdd154dd2e731150?bug_id=6967456