# Eclipse JVM Exit Code 127 when RTC 'Jazz Administration' perspective was opened

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jvm, rtc

I've setup a new RHEL6.5 OS and installed Java 64bit with this [tutorial](http://tecadmin.net/steps-to-install-java-on-centos-5-6-or-rhel-5-6/). The version check shows:

```
[user@localhost bin]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

And JAVA_HOME and JAVA_JRE are set correctly:

```
[user@localhost bin]$ echo $JAVA_HOME && echo $JRE_HOME
/opt/jdk1.7.0_75
/opt/jdk1.7.0_75/jre
```

I installed the [latest version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR2/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz) (4.4.2) of eclipse and was able to execute it. Because of my project setup I've installed the RTC-Plugin with the p2 archive: `RTC-Client-p2Repo-5.0.2.zip`

After the successful start I want to change into the `Jazz Administration` perspective Java crashes every time with this JVM error.

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=127 /opt/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-Xms40m
-Xmx2048m
-jar /home/user/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/user/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150204-1700/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/user/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/user/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316/eclipse_1607.so
-startup /home/user/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 148010
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm /opt/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-Xms40m
-Xmx2048m
-jar /home/user/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Can someone help me with this error? I've tried different parameter in the eclipse.ini. This is my current eclipse.ini used while the errors occure.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/opt/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Did you tried with the recommended version (https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/5.0.2?p=allDownloads) Eclipse 4.2.x IDE, instead of your Eclipse 4.4.x?

Comment: Could you please attach crash report?

Comment: AtVonC no I didn't. I'm downloading it at the moment and give feedback with the 4.2.x Version.
@Ivan which crash report? Eclipse doesn't log any errors, if you pointing in this direction.

Comment: I mean Java crash report like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787793/crash-report-from-jvm

Comment: @vonC no the recommended version has nothing to do with it. :/

Comment: @Ivan where does Java store these crash reports ?

Comment: The location of this log file is usually in working directory. It's possible to define the path to the hs_err_pid file. Add the following JVM Parameter to your existing ones: `-XX:ErrorFile=./hs_err_pid<pid>.log`

Comment: @Ivan : I tried it, but no JVM error message occured. But I guess it wasn't logged or I searched at the wrong places. (~/ | ~/eclipse/ | ~/eclipse/workspace | ~/eclipse/workspace/.metadata )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the point of failure. It's the SWT Browser which causes the problem.

> This is an eclipse problem ([bug 343889](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=343889)).
>   Many of the linux distributions recently underwent an upgrade to xulrunner-2.0 which is incompatible with some versions of eclipse. (even with `xmlrunner-compat` packages)

I found some information about this error in these posts:

- [Error while delivering code in RTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558706/error-while-delivering-code-in-rtc?answertab=votes#tab-top) (Quote Source)
- [SWT Browser & Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695271/swt-browser-eclipse)

After i added these lines to my `eclipse.ini` I encountered another error.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

But this time it was logged in the `.log` within my `.metadata`.

```
!ENTRY com.ibm.team.process.ide.ui 4 0 2015-03-19 03:11:17.361
!MESSAGE Error logged from Process Client UI: 
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:99)
    ...
```

If anyone looks for theses errors, try this posts:

- [How to install XULRunner for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994805/how-to-install-xulrunner-for-eclipse)
- [swt browser No more handles Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130980/swt-browser-no-more-handles-error/7140643#7140643)
- [SWT Browser not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418568/swt-browser-not-working)